# TypeError in Backbonejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-framework

I just trying this below example, but I am getting error “TypeError: _.has is not a function”.

Example: http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/2.html

I have tried with different jQuery version, Backbone uncompressed version. But still I am getting the same error. Any help on this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you included underscore.js in your code?

Comment: Try including latest version of underscore.js <script src="underscore.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks David & Uttam. The problem with older underscorejs version only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have Underscore v. 1.3.1 or greater, and that it's loaded before Backbone.

Comment: As Davide noted, "has" is a method of the underscore library, here is the documentation: 
http://underscorejs.org/#has